local ACME with DNS challenge unbound
I would like to run nginx, traefik, or whatever is needed to do a DNS challenge over ACME.
If possible, without an additional app like Certbot. But even with certbot, as far as I can see, unbound doesn't have an API to set the TXT record. Is this correct?


I plan to set up a local CA.
Unbound will serve as a recursive resolver.
It will also resolve some internal domains.
The main focus is, let's summarize it below, "offline capability."
DNS challenge due to required wildcard capability (required AFAIK)

